# How to set state in TypeScript without getting assignment error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm writing a simple program in React-TypeScript that allows users to submit and render text to the browser.

Upon submit, a new object is generated, that object is saved to state as `document`, which is then spread into a new piece of state called `choreList`, as follows:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    let doc = new ChoreDoc(name,chore,date)
    setDocument(doc)
    setChoreList([...choreList,document])
  }
```

My problem is that I'm getting the following linting error, associated with `[...choreList,document]`:

```
Argument of type '(ChoreDoc | null)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(ChoreDoc | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
```

Any suggestions of how I can type my submit function in order to fix this?

Code in full:

`App.tsx`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Document from './Document'
import './styles.css'

interface Formatter {
  format(): string
}

class ChoreDoc implements Formatter  {
  name:string
  chore:string
  date:string

  constructor(n:string,c:string,d:string){
    this.name = n
    this.chore = c
    this.date = d
  }

  format(){
    return `${this.name} completed this following chore: ${this.chore} (on date: ${this.date})`
  }
}

function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [chore, setChore] = useState('')
  const [date, setDate] = useState('')
  const [document, setDocument] = useState<ChoreDoc | null>(null);
  const [choreList, setChoreList] = useState([])

  const handleNameChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setName(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
  const handleChoreChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setChore(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
  const handleDateChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
      e.preventDefault()
      setDate(e.currentTarget.value)
  }


  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    let doc = new ChoreDoc(name,chore,date)
    setDocument(doc)
    setChoreList([...choreList,document])
  }


  return(
    <>
      <div>
          <form className = 'input-list' onSubmit = {handleSubmit} >
              <label>
              Enter Name <br></br>
              <input type = 'text' name = 'name' onChange = {handleNameChange}></input>
              </label>
              <label>
              Chore <br></br>
              <input type = 'text' name = 'chore' onChange = {handleChoreChange}></input>
              </label>
              <label>
              Date completed <br></br>
              <input type = 'text' name = 'date' onChange = {handleDateChange}></input>
              </label>
              <div>
              <button type = 'submit' >Submit</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div>
      {document && <Document document={document}/>}
      </div>
      </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

```
Document.tsx
```

```
import React from 'react'

interface Formatter {
    format(): string
  }

interface Props {
    document: Formatter;
  }

const Document: React.FC<Props> = ({ document }) => {
    return <h1 className="doc">{document.format()}</h1>;
  };

export default Document
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

(1) Type the `choreList` `useState` properly when it's declared, so that TS understands it'll be an array of documents

(2) `setDocument` does not update the `document` in the current scope, so you'll be calling `setChoreList` with the document from the prior render, not the document that was just created

```
const [choreList, setChoreList] = useState<Array<ChoreDoc>>([])
```

and

```
setChoreList([...choreList,doc])
```